# How to download a php file without executing it?

Tags: php, download

im working on a content management system for that i have to download a php file using php code without executing. any one can help me on this

it is some thing like ftp. i have added the options to upload, edit and download a file. it is working fine. but while downloading a php file it is executed instead of downloading...

What i tried is:

```
<?php
$file = $_REQUEST['file_name'];

if (file_exists($file)) {
    header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
    header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='.basename($file));
    header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
    header('Expires: 0');
    header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0');
    header('Pragma: public');
    header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($file));

    include_once($file);
    exit;
}
?>
```

Comment: Download from where? Via what?

Comment: Download from where to where? Please add more detail

Comment: See my answer for a working example.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You have to load the files content, write the content to the request and set the headers so that it's parsed as force download or octet stream.

For example:

http://server.com/download.php?name=test.php

Contents of download.php:

```
  <?php 
  $filename = $_GET["name"]; //Obviously needs validation
  ob_end_clean();
  header("Content-Type: application/octet-stream; "); 
  header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary"); 
  header("Content-Length: ". filesize($filename).";"); 
  header("Content-disposition: attachment; filename=" . $filename);
  readfile($filename);
  die();
  ?>
```

This code works without any modification. Although it needs validation and some security features.

Comment: This works. But you shouldn't really be doing it this way - PHP is not designed to handle file downloads (this won't support resuming, capping and has a large overhead) use something which is designed to handle this problem: a file server.

Comment: Yeah, that's 100% true! However this is what OP asked for.

Comment: Yeah totally, was just making sure he was aware of the potential issues!

Answer (score 3):

The server somehow identifies file that should be executed instead of downloaded. You have to exclude the .php file you want to download from that handling. The easiest is probably to rename the file to .php.txt.

Otherwise you should be able to configure the server to not process that particular file, or the path were it is located. How you do that depends on which server you are running.

Comment: I use this trick to allow users to download a php file.

Name the PHP file `file.php.txt`. Then add it in the the HTML a tag like this: `<a href="file.php.txt" download="file.php">Download</a>`.

Answer (score 1):

If such php file is located on the same server/website, then just open it as normal file, e.g. `$fileContents = file_get_contents($filename);`

If file is on another server, you have few **possible** options:

1) Access it via FTP (if you have login details and access)

2) Have special URL Rewrite rule on that server which will instruct web server to send file as plain text instead of executing it (e.g. `somefile.php.txt`)

3) Have special script on that server and by passing file name as a parameter it will return content of that file (e.g. `http://example.com/showfile.php?file=somefile.php`)

Answer (score 1):

This is how to download a php file instead of executing it.

Trust me it works! ..download the file php with own risk :)

```
<?php
function downloadThatPhp($nameOfTheFile)
    {
        header("Pragma: public");
        header("Expires: 0"); // set expiration time
        header("Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0");
        header("Content-Type: application/text/x-vCard");
        header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=".basename($nameOfTheFile).";");
        header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");
        header("Content-Length: ".filesize($nameOfTheFile));
        @readfile($nameOfTheFile);
        exit(0);
    }

    // and this how to use:
    // download that php file with your own risk :)
    $file = $_REQUEST['file_name'];
    $downloadThis = "http://domain-name.com/".$file;
    if (file_exists($file)) {
        downloadThatPhp($downloadThis);
    }
?>
```

Hope this helps you bro :)

Comment: It will only download if the file (name) is strictly local and __without the url__. If non-local or local but with URL (even for the same server), it will fail; the download happens but the __codes are not there__. This is tested on centos7/php7.x and centos8/php8.x servers.

Answer (score 0):

You can read alot about it on [php.net/header](http://php.net/header), but to force a download, you can use a force-download header. [This comment is amazing](http://dk.php.net/manual/en/function.header.php#102175), check it out! :-)

Answer (score 0):

if someone is looking to do this in his/her .htaccess file:

```
Header set Content-Disposition attachment
AddType application/octet-stream .php
```

or

```
<FilesMatch "\.(?i:php)$">
  ForceType application/octet-stream
  Header set Content-Disposition attachment
</FilesMatch>
```