# Encoding PHP without executing it

Tags: php, html, ftp

I have an PHP file which I want to display in a **textarea** via PHP. But when I use `file_get_contents()` to display it, it seems like the PHP has already executed before it displays in the **textarea**.

I tried to encode it with `htmlspecialchars()`, but that didn't work, because the PHP was still executing.

Is there any way to do this or is it really impossible?

Comment: file_get_contents() will __not__ execute code if the code is accessed via the filesystem, please show your code for rendering this

Comment: see this (possible duplicate) -> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6321307/how-to-download-a-php-file-without-executing-it

Answer (score 1):

If you use a local filesystem path in your `file_get_contents()` call, for example:

```
$text = file_get_contents("/var/www/domain.com/filename.php");
```

the PHP won't be executed.

Comment: I think you need to clear out what you mean by a "local filesystem". `echo file_get_contents('/var/www/test.php');` certainly parses the PHP as well, and on most (paid) servers you cannt provide a full local path.

Comment: @david `echo file_get_contents('/var/www/test.php');` will never parse the PHP. Only a request for a web URL will: `echo file_get_contents('http://www.example.com/test.php');` You can always provide a valid filesystem path. Occasionally directories are inaccessible for PHP (through the `open_basedir` setting) but there is always *some* directory that is accessible. I added an example

Comment: Yes, or no path at all -> `echo file_get_contents('test.php');` seems not to be parsed either (at least not on localhost/ubuntu/apache). I confused myself, test.php called itself and there were other things going on below, sry :(

Answer (score 0):

I've fixed this problem by first downloading the file via FTP, so I would have a local file. Then I used the local path to open the file in a textarea with:

```
echo '<textarea>' . file_get_contents($localPathToFile) . '</textarea>';
```

But because there was a

```
</textarea>
```

Inside of the file, I had to replace that by using:

```
$filecontents = str_replace("</textarea>","&lt;/textarea&gt;",$localPathToFile);
```

Now the code works fine and displays the PHP inside the textarea